# flash player stuck while playing in chrome over SSL

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, flash

I am using below versions:

Protocal: HTTPS (SSL)
Chrome Vesrion: 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)
Adobe Flash Player Plug-in Version: 24.0.0.186

Issue: When I am trying to play a flash video over SSL on chrome browser, its not playing the video content. The browser just loads the first initial screen and does not proceed further to play the content of the video.

I could not reproduce this issue in other browsers like IE 11 and Firefox 45.4.0

In chrome, its working fine over HTTP protocol.

I am not sure of what causing this issue whether its browser, flash player plug-in or protocol issue.

Can you please help me out in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but it may be that Chrome blocks the Flash element, when the page is serverd via HTTPS but the Flash element is serverd via HTTP only. Apart from that you should probably avoid Flash, because it poses a security risk. So get rid of the Flash player.

Comment: Do you have a link to show loading issue in action? Is the video file also served from SSL? Make sure your html file (page), swf file (playback app), mp4 or flv file (videos) are all from same protocol ie: all `http` or all `https`.  Loading from same server location (rather than just same protocol) is best option..

Answer (score 0):

Just change the link to the shockwave/flash document adress to https.